# CSS transaction doesn't work in accordion with 100 percent sub menu

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have simple accordion menu using `jQuery` and `CSS` transaction for show sub menu. like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nk-menu list-unstyled" id="side-menu">
    <li class="nk-menu-item has-sub">
      <a class="nk-menu-link nk-menu-toggle" href="javascript: void(0);">
        <span class="nk-menu-text">First</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="nk-menu-sub">
        <li class="nk-menu-item">
          <a class="nk-menu-link" href="">
            <span>Sub 1</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nk-menu-item has-sub">
      <a class="nk-menu-link nk-menu-toggle" href="javascript: void(0);">
        <span class="nk-menu-text">Second</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.nk-menu-toggle', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let $this = $(this);
  if ($this.parent().hasClass('active')) {
    $this.parent().removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.nk-menu').find('li').removeClass('active');
    $this.closest('li').toggleClass('active');
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
.nk-menu-sub {
  border-top: 1px solid #2a4163;
  background: #8FBC8F;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin: 0 0 7px 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: .7s ease;
  -o-transition: .7s ease;
  transition: .7s ease;
}

.active>.nk-menu-sub {
  height: 50px; // change this line to 100%
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

In action, This code has worked truly with specific size like `50px` for `sub menu`, But when I need to change `height` to `100%` for dynamic area in `.active>.nk-menu-sub`, css transaction doesn't work and `sub menu` have a delay and lag.

How do can I fox this problem?!

Demo [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/pz6sb83d/)

Answer (score 0):

As per your code `height` value is necessary to provide them with some value.
So, I have modified your code as per your requirement.
I hope you like it.

Please refer to the link [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ae16xqms/22/)